# Start values work for one data frame but not for another each more than 1000 subjects (nls)

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I have a data frame

```
> head(APD_irr)
   Serial_number Lot Wafer Irradiated Amplification Voltage Dark_current
125     912009913   9   912          1       50.8258 335.965    -0.069231
126     912009913   9   912          1       54.3855 337.966    -0.080305
127     912009913   9   912          1       58.3014 339.959    -0.059258
128     912009913   9   912          1       62.6758 341.956    -0.062005
129     912009913   9   912          1       67.5537 343.965    -0.058412
130     912009913   9   912          1       72.9996 345.965    -0.058341
```

which I fit via

[image: Formula]

with the nls model:

```
func<- function(Voltage, p0, p1, p2){ 1/(1-(Voltage/p0)^p1) + p2  }
Fits<- lapply(split(APD_irr, APD_irr$Serial_number), function(dat){
  p0start<- max(dat$Voltage) * 1.01
  nls(Amplification ~ func(Voltage, p0, p1, p2),
      data = dat, start = list(p0 = p0start, p1 = 0.1, p2 = -10))
})
```

The problem arises when I want to apply the same model to a very similar data frame, meaning the same items after a specific treatment:

```
> head(APD_non_irr)
   Serial_number Lot Wafer Irradiated Amplification Voltage Dark_current
62     912009913   9   912          0       107.807 353.971    -0.218123
63     912009913   9   912          0       119.441 355.983    -0.227814
64     912009913   9   912          0       133.200 357.983    -0.199640
65     912009913   9   912          0       149.796 359.983    -0.168064
66     912009913   9   912          0       170.113 361.975    -0.136797
67     912009913   9   912          0       195.890 363.989    -0.113058
```

I can't get the model to converge:

```
 Error in nls(Amplification ~ func(Voltage, p0, p1, p2), data = dat,  : 
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
```

I really tried a lot by tuning the parameters and also the region of interest:
I limit both data frames to a smaller Amplification region with a lower limit of `50` and an upper limit of `350`:

```
APD_irr<- subset(APD_irr, subset = Amplification > 50 & Amplification < 350)
APD_irr<- subset(APD_non_irr, subset = Amplification > 50 & Amplification < 350)
```

Hence, as you can see, `p0` is estimated by the data itself through `p0start<- max(dat$Voltage) * 1.01` but changes on this only make it worse..

If anyone can help me out I would highly appreciate that! Thus, thanks a lot in advance!
I've uploaded code and data on: https://ufile.io/b7tkx

edit: I found one of the items creating problems. The red curve is fittable but the blue one not:

[image: Plot]